# Is there garbage collection in PHP?

Tags: php, memory-management, garbage-collection

I know that in PHP you don't have to free memory.
Is it reached by garbage collector?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes there is, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20091124213723/http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/10)'s a nice article describing its pitfalls. In PHP > 5.3.0, there is also the [gc_enable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-enable.php) function.

Comment: One gotcha not included in that article is anonymous functions, created with create_function(). [These are not subject to garbage collection.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php#70691)

Comment: @Dave Lancea   Good observation. I would just point out however that your link points on a comment made on 2007, thus perhaps it is not like this anymore in 2017 (but maybe it is, I could not find more info on the subject).

Comment: @DaveLancea, hopefully, there is no `create_function()` as of PHP 8.0.0. :)

Answer (score 11):

PHP has a combination of garbage collection and reference counting. The latter is the main mode of managing memory, with the garbage collector picking up the pieces that the ref counter misses (circular references). Before 5.3, php only had ref-counting, and even in 5.3 it's the still how memory will usually be freed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is also session cleanup done by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 3):

since 5.3.0 there is garbage collection support. please check this very informative article from php.net http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Answer (score 1):

Since 5.3.0 you can force garbage collection by using `gc_collect_cycles function`.