# Disable Garbage Collection

Tags: php, garbage-collection

How do I disable garbage collection for a long running php cli script? I am handling unsetting of variables in the script.

Comment: @levu: Does that disable the collector until max available for a process is consumed?

Comment: Hm, why do you need this? Seems a _lot_ of work, and the gc handler is vastly improved in PHP >= 5.3....

Comment: Hm, anybody care to explain the downvote on this question? It's as valid as questions go.... Voting up just because I don't agree with the down :)

Comment: @Wrikken I didnt dv but I could imagine it's because [it's very much a General Reference question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).

Comment: @Wrikken: I did. My intention wasn't "its an invalid question" (else I would closevote it), but "its not useful". The reasons: a) The question is like "Im going to shoot myself into the foot" b) The question _before_ this one should be "How does `unset()`/GC work?". Someone may read this and may come to the conclusion, that it is a good idea or even (worse) that this is a kind of use-case in memory-critical applications.

Comment: The issue I have is that my script can sleep for a long time, over an hour in some cases. And the garbage collector sneaks in and takes out my variables while the script is sleeping. At least, that is what I think is happening. The townspeople are scared and I call upon the good folks of SO to help them deal with this menace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unsetting variables does *not* free memory! It just removes the reference from the variable to the corresponding value. Once any value have a ref-count of `0` the GC collects the value and frees its allocated memory. If it would be possible to completely disable the GC you would break your interpreter (in best case): You will have many many unreferenced data in your memory, that will never get cleaned. Thats called "memory leak".

[Is there garbage collection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735492/is-there-garbage-collection-in-php)

Comment: So, why does that setting exist then?

Comment: Hi @Meglio When you assign and un-/re-assign many variables, for example in a loop, it is easy to trigger the GC many times, which will have a bigger performance impact. In that case -- the popular "you know what you are doing"-case -- it can make sense to temporary disable the gc. Especially in job-like scripts, which you know will end soon anyway, you can just consume the memory and let die OS free it once the process stops.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @KingCrunch. So for a long loop, say at 1M iterations, it might make sense to turn GC OFF before the loop starts, and turn it back ON after it completes - if performance is more important than memory. Is this the case?

Answer (score 7):

In my case the issue was related with the *Zend Server* running as a *cli* -- It crashed often and randomly. On the internet I found about disabling the 'garbage collector'

To do so,

**in php.ini**

```sh
zend.enable_gc = Off
```

also, it can be changed directly in the cli

```sh
$ php -d zend.enable_gc=0 your_script.php
```

Comment: This helped me on php 5.3.x - I guess due to GC running in beta mode for this version.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the Garbage Collector with

- [`gc_disable` — Deactivates the circular reference collector](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-disable.php)

or via the ini setting:

- [`zend.enable_gc boolean` - Enables or disables the circular reference collector.](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.zend.enable-gc)

However, using `unset` does not free memory. It only marks variables for the GC to collect afaik. See the chapter on [Garbage Collection in the PHP Manual for details.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php)

Comment: Tried that, it's only available in 5.3+, I'm using 5.2.17

Comment: Only affects the circular-refernce GC, not the "common" one.

Comment: @King there is no "common" one. This is the only GC.

Comment: Thats just wrong. In short: The circular-GC comes with PHP5.3 and you really believe, that there were never a GC before 5.3? In slightly longer: There is absolutely no way in PHP to allocate, or free memory. You can only create or remove references to values, that the interpreter allocates for you.

Comment: @Gordon: PHP has had a garbage collector for a long time.  Since way back before 5.3.  Prior to 5.3, it was a simple refcount based GC that just checked the number of references to a variable (not looking into circular references).  It runs after you explicitly unset a variable, and after you leave a scope (and at script termination).  5.3 added a circular reference collector to that basic functionality.  Disabling gc_disable() just stops the circular GC mechanism from running.  The refcount primitive one still runs...  Otherwise unset() and scope changes would never free memory...

Comment: @ircmaxell I never said PHP didnt have a GC before 5.3 and you saw what Artefacto answered to my question. There is no "common" GC in addition to the refcounting one. Might be `gc_disable` "only" disables the cycling, but there is just one GC. There is not two GCs.

Answer (score 2):

Source: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php):

> Besides changing the `zend.enable_gc` configuration setting, it is also possible to turn the garbage collecting mechanism on and off by calling `gc_enable()` or `gc_disable()` respectively.