# Allowed memory size exhausted while synchronizing images with use of imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, image, memory-limit

I am trying to synchronize images from one directory to another using imagecreatefromjpeg to resize the images in the process. In total the script has to process 15 GB of image files. At first the script was running just fine until i bumped into a memory limit. I found that this was fixed by setting the following code:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","64M");
```

But after a lot more images where synchronized the same problem occurred again, and again, and again until the fifth time where I set the limit to 1000M, but that didn't fix the problem anymore. Even after trying 9999M it still gave me the same error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1778384896 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57060 bytes)
```

I checked my phpinfo() and found that it was correctly set:

```
Directive     Local Value Master Value  
memory_limit  99999M      512M
```

Can anyone give me another option to increase the memory limit?

Adding the code I use for the synchronization:

```
// SYNCHRONIZE FILES
// GET SOURCE FILES
if ($handle = opendir($hrdir)) {                
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(is_file($hrdir.$file)) {                             
            $nieuwehr_array[$file] = filemtime($hrdir.$file);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}   

// GET EXISTING FILES
if ($handle = opendir($hrdestinationdir)) {             
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(is_file($hrdestinationdir.$file)) {              
            $huidigehr_array[$file] = filemtime($hrdestinationdir.$file);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}           

$hr_added_array = array();
$hr_modified_array = array();

// ADD NEW OR MODIFIED FILES
foreach($nieuwehr_array as $file => $change_date) {
    if(!isset($huidigehr_array[$file]) || $change_date != $huidigehr_array[$file]) {
        new createImage($hrdir, $file, $hrdestinationdir, 800, 600);
        touch($hrdestinationdir.$file,$change_date);
        if(isset($huidigehr_array[$file])) {                
            $hr_modified_array[] = $file;
        } else {                
            $hr_added_array[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

My appologies in advance for some dutch variable names.

Edit 1-12-2011 12:00:
Just found out that the problem was an image file of 62MB. It looks like file larger then give or take 55MB are the problem. Does anybody know what could cause this?

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak. You should synchronize the images one at a time making sure to 'take out the garbage' before continuing to another image. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735492/is-there-garbage-collection-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735492/is-there-garbage-collection-in-php)

Comment: I uploaded the code I use to synchronize the images. As you can see I use "createImage" (which is a class that resizes and relocates an image in its constructor) to copy the missing images to the destination directory. The memory used in this class should be garbaged after finishing right?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone give me another option to increase the memory limit?

Why don't you ask how to write a program with more sane memory consumption?

Are you reading all your images in array, not one by one?

And what, on the earth, you call "synchronize"?

> `new createImage($hrdir, $file, $hrdestinationdir, 800, 600);`

it seems this line being your problem.

Regarding the image size,

1. No file size affects the memory but image dimensions.
2. No image, even if 64M of compressed size, can consume 10G of RAM.
   It is indeed memory leak in your code, not particular image.

Add some calls to the `memory_get_usage` in your code and see the progress.

```
echo "MEM: ",number_format( memory_get_usage()/(1024*1024) ),"MB used\n";
```

Comment: Synchronize is meant as: I have a directory with images and I have an empty directory. By synchronizing I want all the images from the one directory into the other but with a different width and height.

As for storing the files. I create an array containing the filenames en creation dates of each file and have two separate arrays for both the directories so that i can compare these to see if a file already exists.

Comment: While looping through one array and comparing to the other I call a function "createImage" each time I find a file that does not exist (so everything done in this function should be garbaged when the function returns).

Comment: it seems not everything. why can't you just copy the image?

Comment: Because users upload extremely large images I have to resize them before/while copying them.

Comment: you're not "calling a function", you are creating an object. Every time you are to process an image. What about creating an object ONCE, but call it's *function* to create an image?

Comment: Okay, I thought that when I didn't put the object into a variable it would be garbaged after finishing the constructor. But I created the situation you described. A class called "imageResizer" with a function "resizeAndMove", but I still get the same error. Could it be that the memory is never cleared? If so, how can I clear it before running the script again?

Comment: Would you please comment on my last edit. I just found out the problem was caused by an extremely large image file.

Comment: done. I think we had to be started from that - from getting some information