# Do I need to destroy objects in PHP after using them?

Tags: php, object

How crucial is object destruction in PHP? is it important to destroy objects in PHP after using them? because unlike java, PHP doesn't have a garbage collector (nothing that I know of)

Comment: PHP most certainly does have a garbage collector.

Comment: There is a built in [Garbage Collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) (also known as GC) mechanism that is part of PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to destroy objects in the general case, and PHP certainly [does have a garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735492/is-there-garbage-collection-in-php). Moreover, most simple scripts would not even really need one because the whole environment is torn down and rebuilt for every HTTP request; the garbage collector helps those scripts that would run out of memory while serving a *single* request.

#### Exceptions to the general case:

You might want to "lose" all references to objects that consume a large amount of memory and/or wrap unmanaged resources; this is usually as easy as

```
$largeObject = null; // reference to previous value lost
```

If that was the last reference to `$largeObject`, then:

- PHP will immediately call the destructor (if one exists); you might want to do for objects which are wrapping unmanaged resources (e.g. database connections, sockets, etc) if your script is long-lived.
- The memory that the object takes up will now be eligible for garbage collection. However, collection will not occur on the spot but at some later point where more memory is required (although you can call [`gc_collect_cycles`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) to force garbage collection at any time).

Of course all of this does not come into consideration in the typical case of "service a request and then exit".

Comment: +1, See here for more informations : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is not an issue you have to take into account.
Here is an article about one guy who met this issue.

http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/262

you can use this function to destruct whatever object you like within your classes.

```
function __destruct()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

An object can remain in the memory for the duration of the request,
or when invoking from command line, as long as the script remains running.

Comment: I'm removing your edit; this question is about PHP, and you have included information about the .NET garbage collector, which is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in [Garbage Collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) (also known as GC) mechanism that is part of PHP 5.3.

```
<?php
    gc_enable(); // Enable Garbage Collector
    var_dump(gc_enabled()); // true
    var_dump(gc_collect_cycles()); // # of elements cleaned up
    gc_disable(); // Disable Garbage Collector
?>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Php has a garbage collector, but in practice there are many cases when php does not free memory until `unset` function will be executed. These cases are about singleton, xml, might be fabrics. In our company we patched php and logged all memory allocation and add unset function to code. 
But in web development this is not so critical.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested garbage collection will do the job at the end of execution, however if you have a long running cron then you might run into problems if/when you are working with large amounts of data or huge arrays.

The solution at this point is to use unset($object) which calls the objects magic __destruct() function which you can use if you want to do anything with the object (such as persist the data in the database).