# Decent memory profiling tool for php

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've built an auto mailer application using the SendGrid official PHP library and SMTP API(The auto mailer runs as a cron job on an Ubuntu server).

The memory limit on the production server is set to 32M, and yet on one of the first runs of the application on the production server I got the message

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted, wast trying to allocate 256478 bytes

Which makes no sense at all since 256478 < 33554432, and yet I suspect that I have a memory leak somewhere.

According [to this post](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/262), PHP has memory leaks issue, when dealing with reciprocal relationships between objects, I am using my own Wrapper class inorder to make the code more readable and structed, a main mailService class, and also a class per each task, that implements an interface, and returns all the specific data(Headers, sub values, recipient list) per each email.

I'll start with adding a destructor to my interface and to each class, in order to reassure that there are no memory leaks, but I am not sure that this will solve the issue, because according to a memory benchmark that I have performed, most of the execution time, and the memory is consumed by the MailTransport.php class of SwiftMailer.

So my question I basically, how can I reset the memory usage of this class per each iteration?, is there something built in, or should I implement method as such on my own?.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Small visualization:[image]

Comment: Are you building a list of all your email recipients? That coupld easily be a memory hog, especially with a low 32M limit

Comment: Well, each specific task is meant only for certain users, the NotifyTokenExpiry is only for users that had their token expired in the past month, the topScores are only for actively ranked users and so on, and at the end of each iteration, I unset() the member that holds the recipients list, and also asign a null value to it afterward to be sure.
Anyways, you must have a decent amount of emails to exceed a limitation of 32M, I have only tested my application with somewhere below 500 emails

Answer (score 5):

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted, wast trying to allocate 256478 bytes

Means that PHP is trying to allocate an **additional** 256478 above and beyond what it has already allocated during the running of the script, and that **additional** request is what has pushed the total memory used over the 33554432 threshold.

Earlier versions of PHP had memory problems when they encountered cyclic references between objects, though this has improved with 5.4.... whether you are affected will depend on which version of PHP you are running, and whether your classes actually contain such cyclic references

Comment: I am running PHP 5.4, how can I trace and fix possible memory leaks?.
It seems improbable to me that an application consumes this large amount of memory when all what it's doing is sending emails.
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: As I mentioned previously, if you're building up a list of recipients for your emails, that can be memory consuming - but that 32MB is for PHP plus all its modules plus your script

Comment: I did the math, my email template weights 8 KB, and is loaded once per each email type, the email recipient list consists of a regular key => val array, and has < 500 entries in it, and then there are the substitution values, they can weight up to several MB for a list of up to 500 recipients, but no more.
so unless php is using 25MB of the allocated 32MB, it makes no sense :(

Comment: Instructions on using xdebug to trace memory usage -http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2012/04/tracing-php-memory-usage-using-xdebug-and-mamp-on-mac/ - for mamp on mac's, but should be applicable to all platforms

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, I am running Ubuntu 12.10, and using Sublime 2 IDE.

Comment: That shouldn't stop you using xdebug - the principle is identical regardless of platform

Comment: Yeah, but for sublime there is only one beta, buggy plugin for Xdebugger, by Kidari(on github), he wrote this plugin while still learning the Sbulime API, and it has many issues and limitations.

And learning to use Eclipse for that matter is an overkill, I personally prefer using the simplest tools + bash for SQL console, git etc.

Comment: I think you misunderstand your tool set. Sublime Text is not an IDE, first off. Secondly, I would attempt this problem in two phases, cut the problem in half doing the first half of the list, and add some [memory_get_useage()](http://php.net/memory-get-usage) function calls to track the amount of memory you are using. If that still gives you the error, cut the problem again in half using only a quarter this time, and so on, and so forth until you find a workable unit. From there, you can find out what is taking up so much space by what you are initializing.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has since 5.3 [garbage collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) features you can try and use to see if it helps your perticular situation. Also see [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735492/is-there-garbage-collection-in-php)